# findall(X,condition,List) list is filled with pointers and not real objects

Tags: prolog, prolog-findall

I am trying to get a list full of objects from the database that fit my condition.

Here is my database:

> ```
> student(1234,[statistics/a,algorithms/b,prolog/a,infi/b]).
> student(4321,[java/a,algorithms/a,prolog/b,probability/b,infi/a]).
> student(1111,[algorithms/a,prolog/a,c/a,infi/a]).
> student(2222,[c/b,algorithms/b,prolog/b,infi/a]).
> student(3333,[java/b,algorithms/b,prolog/a,infi/a]).
> student(4444,[java/a,c/a,prolog/a]).
> student(5555,[java/a,c/a,prolog/b,infi/b]).
> student(6666,[java/a,c/a,prolog/b,infi/b,probability/b,algorithms/b]).
> ```

I wrote a predicat that queries which student has a string in the list attached to him that has: "infi/a"

```
findall(Ns,(student(Id,List),subset([infi/a],List)),L1)
```

The problem is that L1 does not return me a list as the following:

> ```
> L1 = [student(2222,[c/b,algorithms/b,prolog/b,infi/a]),
>       student(1111,[algorithms/a,prolog/a,c/a,infi/a]) etc...]
> ```

It returns:

```
L1 = [_G2044, _G2041, _G2038, _G2035].
```

Why does this happen and how can I fix this?

Comment: Those aren't "pointers". Those are uninstantiated anonymous variables. It is because your `Ns` doesn't appear anywhere in your `findall/3` condition (second argument), so `findall/3` fills `L1` with empty variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably need to look up the specifications of the [**`findall/3`**](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=findall/3) predicate the **first parameters is the `Template`** (or yield): it specifies what you want to put into the list.

So you should not simply write `X`, but a term in which you are interested. For instance:

```
findall(Id,(student(Id,List),subset([infi/a],List)),L1).
```

will generate all the `Id`s of the students with `infi/a` in their list of courses; or if you are interested in the `student/2` objects, you can write:

```
findall(student(Id,List),(student(Id,List),subset([infi/a],List)),L1).
```

So typically you work with the variable(s) you specify in the `Goal` (the second parameter), in case there is a free variable in your yield, it will make new free variables.

Comment: Thanks! This did the trick. From some reason it was hard for me to grasp this "first parameters is the Template", but now after your answer I understand the concept!